# Registrar un contacto usando la api de InfusionSoft con NodeJs

Tags: nodejs

necesito crear un contacto en infusionSoft usando la API.

EL problema es que la documentación no es muy completa, por que todo lo orientan al uso de los SDK y lastimosamente no tienen SDK para NodeJS.

En este link de la documentación dice como se crea, pero no es nada claro sobre los parametros, sobre todo porque necesito relacionarlo con un formulario.
[Crear contacto infusionSoft API](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact)

si alguien tiene experiencia con esta api, 
le agradezco mucho.

Comment: Podrías indicar qué quieres hacer con el formulario, es decir, cuál sería la secuencia que quieres lograr. Por otra parte, para utilizar la API (que es [XML-RPC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC))necesitas enviar mensajes XML al servidor e interpretar su respuesta (también en XML), cambia XML por JSON y casi, casi, lo mismo. Podrías utilizar por ejemplo esta [librería](https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc).

Comment: si, yo entiendo bien el funcionamiento, de hecho ya hice la integración y obtengo los formularios registrados en infusionSoft.
El problema que tengo es el registro de un nuevo contacto, pues en la documentación no encuentro claridad de la URL y los parametros necesarios para el registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de tanto insistir por fin logré una solución, quizas sea la única forma.

Lo que hice fue obtener el código HTML del formulario usando la API (esta funcion sí existe). usé un XML como el siguiente:

```
var postData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodCall><methodName>WebFormService.getHTML</methodName><params>'
            +'<param><value><string>'+local.key+'</string></value></param>'
            +'<param><value>'
            +'<int>'+idForm+'</int>'
            +'</value></param>'
            +'</params></methodCall>';
```

lo siguiente es obtener los campos `Input` del formulario y la url del `Action`
para finalmente hacer una petición post enviando los datos.

De esta forma el registro del contacto se hace relacionado al formulario especifico.

Gracias a todos, espero esta solución le pueda ayudar a alguien.

Saludos.

Comment: Excelente! Muy bueno el aporte!

Answer (score 0):

Punto de partida tomando el ejemplo de la documentacion (el link que enviaste). No está para nada probado, pero puede que te ayude.

Parto del [ejemplo](https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc/blob/master/example/client_server.js) de [node-xlmrpc](https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc). Y del código de ejemplo para [Ruby](https://github.com/infusionsoft/API-Sample-Code/blob/master/Ruby/ruby.rb).

```
//AppName calculo que lo tienes que reemplazar por el propio

var clientOptions = { host: 'AppName.infusionsoft.com', port: 443 , path: '/api/xmlrpc'}
var client = xmlrpc.createClient(clientOptions)

var data= { FirstName: 'John',LastName: 'Doe',Email:'there_he_go@itsjohndoe.com' }

//Asumo que token_value el token OAuth2 ya lo obtuviste

client.methodCall('ContactService.add', [token_value,data], function (error, value) {
    client.methodCall('getStruct', null, function (error, value) {
      console.log('Get ContactService.add Response (on next line): ')
      console.log(value)
    })
})
```

Deberías conseguir que salga el XML del ejemplo de la documentación (o algo bastante parecido por donde empezar).